# Can Green Set Items be picked up by other players?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know that all the drops from mobs are visible and can be picked from the ground by all the players in the same group, but I have the sensation that for the Green Set Items is a little bit different and only one player can pick a Green Set Item. I think so 'cause all the times that green items dropped with other players I've the luck to pick it and nobody else ran at the point where the green item has dropped after I've picked it.

Someone could clarify me whether **all** items can be picked by all players?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All item drops from mobs (and also chests, armor racks, etc.) are only visible to you. Each player in a party receives their own drops from mobs. This means that you are the only one who can see and pick up and items that drop for you, and that you cannot see or pickup items that drop for other party members. This applies to normal, magic, rare, legendary, and set items.

Comment: Only items that are visible to everyone are those dropped by players themselves.

Answer (score 4):

To expand the answer before:

Every party member gets his own item drop that can be seen on the floor only by that person until it is picked up. That said, it means you can get a set item, but your team members can get nothing. For example if you trigger the shelf in Halls of Agony, you may or may not have the drop from it, and it can be normal, magic, rare, legendary or legendary set.

If there are 4 of you in a party, there could be a (very rare) occasion when the same shelf drops nothing for you, rare for one of your friends, legendary for another and the fourth gets legendary set. All the variations are possible.

Each legendary drop can be shared with another party member for 2 hours from the time it dropped on you. That means, if you get a drop that doesn't give you any boost, but boosts your friend in the party, you can give the item to him/her by dropping it on the floor again from your inventory.

This only works if the person was in the game when the item dropped.

TL;DR: The legendary and set items can be traded inside the same party for two hours after drop. Direct drop (the drop that was not picked up yet) that you see on your screen cannot be seen by anybody else in the party unless you pick it up and drop it again.